# How does Apple's Power Nap interact with File Vault?

Tags: macos, security, filevault

If a machine is periodically waking up to check for updates with Power Nap, does this also mean the disk encryption keys are always in RAM? If so, this makes a DMA attack against a "sleeping" Mac possible.

Comment: How would this be different from normal sleep?

Comment: Certainly it's different than sleep-to-disk, isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

In general, Apple disables FireWire DMA in states where the computer isn't unlocked for use. There were some states they missed early on (see [Todd Garrison's description of the problem](http://www.frameloss.org/2011/09/18/firewire-attacks-against-mac-os-lion-filevault-2-encryption/)), but they tightened the access controls in 10.7.2 (see CVE-2011-3215 [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5002)).

Power nap adds a new DMA-should-be-disabled state, so there's a possibility that it might have reintroduced this vulnerability, but I would expect Apple to have handled this correctly. Unfortunately, I don't know of anyone who's actually tested it (and I don't have a power-nap-capable Mac myself).

Answer (score 1):

Unless Apple messed up and writes the keys or passphrase insecurely, then the Mac is no more vulnerable than when it is running or sleeping normally.